# Effect of Cursor on performance of Bulk data loading

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am using Postgresql 9.3.
I searched for best practices for bulk data loading and got lot of information about indexes, triggers, GUC parameters, but still in doubt about effect of CURSOR and TRANSACTION on bulk data loading.

Could anyone explore on this?

Thanks

Ranjan

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Which problem are you solving? What is the code that is giving you a problem? How do your tables look like? How do you do the "bulk loading"? What are your stored functions doing with the cursor? Are you running the bulk load and the cursors at the same time?

Comment: I am listing down different best practices of bulk loading. So considering all    different techniques would be helpful for bulk loading.